# Long term retention not available in Canada East?

Tags: azure-sql-database

I attempted to configure long term retention for my Azure SQL server but it informs me it is not available in the region used by the database - Canada East. Anyone know why? How do I find what regions it is available in? I can find no clue on the Azure site or MS forums as to why it would not be available here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [BOL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-long-term-retention) *'Long-term backup retention is currently in preview and available in the following regions: Australia East, Australia Southeast, Brazil South, Central US, East Asia, East US, East US 2, India Central, India South, Japan East, Japan West, North Central US, North Europe, South Central US, Southeast Asia, West Europe, and West US.'*. That does not include Canada East at this moment.

Comment: @lin Leng - MSFT Do you know when this will be live in other regions. Looking for `UK South`. I can see no reason why this feature is being held back for different regions. Its been in preview for ages now!

Comment: UPDATE 04/19: looks like this has finally been released to all regions! https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/sql-database-long-term-backup-retention-preview-includes-major-updates/